# how to do grouping with one or more index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
Id    Freq     ID2   PSC
a1     0        xy    33
a1     0        yz    35
a1     1        xz    60
a2     0        pq    70
a2     1        qr     75
a2     0        rs     80
```

output should be

```
Id    Freq     ID2   PSC
a1     0        xy    33
                yz    35
a1     1        xz    60
a2     0        pq     70
                rs     80
a2     1        qr     75
```

after that check a1 and freq=o psc shlould be unique

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you want to do?

If you want to mask the duplicated values with empty string (or NA) to highlight the consecutive duplicates like it would appear on a MultiIndex you could use:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['Id', 'Freq'])
m = df.duplicated(['Id', 'Freq'])

df.loc[m, ['Id', 'Freq']] = ''
```

output:

```
   Id Freq ID2  PSC
0  a1    0  xy   33
1           yz   35
2  a1    1  xz   60
3  a2    0  pq   70
5           rs   80
4  a2    1  qr   75
```

Note that this denaturates your data, so you should only do this for display purposes.

Another option, set the columns as MultiIndex:

```
df.set_index(['Id', 'Freq']).sort_index()
```

The display will hide the consecutive duplicates, not exactly the way you want though.

[image: multiindex]

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the Pandas functions `set_index` and `sort_index`. For your specific problem let's say that you have a dataset called `df`

```
df.set_index(['Id','Freq'])
```

will give you

```
        ID2 PSC
Id  Freq        
a1  0   xy  33
    0   yz  35
    1   xz  60
a2  0   pq  70
    1   qr  75
    0   rs  80
```

Then you can decide if you want to sort by the specific index of your choice (to get unique values).

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    dd.iloc[1:,:2]=''
    return dd

df1.groupby(["Id","Freq"]).apply(function1)
```

output:

```
   Id Freq ID2  PSC
0  a1    0  xy   33
1           yz   35
2  a1    1  xz   60
3  a2    0  pq   70
5           rs   80
4  a2    1  qr   75
```